# How can I change the variable of my Object?

Tags: java, class, object, variables, instance

I googled alot and the problem gives me a Headache because nobody can help me with it on Discord. Now I am here for help.

Thats the Class I use to make the Object

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Konto mats = new Konto("Mats", 200);
        mats.getAccount();
    }
}
```

That is the class of it:

```
public class Konto extends Bankautomat{
    String name;
    int balance;

    String prefix = "[Deutsche Bank]";

    public Konto(String name, int balance){
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
        System.out.println("New Account successfully registered!");
    }

    public void getAccount(){
        System.out.printf("\n%s\nName: %s\nBalance: %d$\n", prefix, name, balance);
    }

}
```

And now I want to make a Bankautomat class where I can deposit money on the Konto from "Mats"

```
public class Bankautomat {

    public void deposit(int amount){

    }
}
```

But I cant use mats.balance += amount
and the set or get things also dont help me
please help thank you <3

Comment: How about moving the balance into Bankautomat class?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up, `Konto` extends `Bankautomat` right now. In other words, all `Konto`s are `Bankautomat`s but the reverse is not the case. Since you only declare the field `balance` in the `Konto` class, this means it's a property of `Konto`s but not necessarily of all `Bankautomat`s, so the `Bankautomat` object doesn't have this unless it's specifically a `Konto`.

To be able to access it in `Bankautomat` you should move the field to the `Bankautomat` class. Then, you'll be able to access it from both, since `Konto` is a `Bankautomat` and will inherit it. Something like this:

```java
public class Konto extends Bankautomat{
    String name;

    String prefix = "[Deutsche Bank]";

    public Konto(String name, int balance){
        super(balance);  // this calls the constructor of the superclass
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("New Account successfully registered!");
    }

    public void getAccount(){
        System.out.printf("\n%s\nName: %s\nBalance: %d$\n", this.prefix, this.name, this.balance);
    }

}
```

and the other class:

```java
public class Bankautomat {
    int balance;

    public Bankautomat(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public void deposit(int amount){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you but why do I have to call the superclass constructor. because I tried without it and it worked too